# Azure DevOps 2020 - GraphClient

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2020

I can't find an easy way to communicate to Microsoft AzureDevops team.
I'm working on some tools that are working with Azure 2019 and there's also Azure 2020 RC right now. Microsoft deprecated SOAP API for 2019. And 2020 also, for REST Client.
Thou in 2019 REST client is not fully provided. GraphClient: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0 is missing there. That means, no way to get UserGraph and Users, but through SOAP API the old way.

I though that maybe with Azure 2020 it's gonna be changed, but actually no.

I'm using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client in newest preview and latest stable version. That are: 16.173.0-preview and 16.153.0. Calling it manually making REST requests won't help either.

My test code:

```
var uriToServer = new Uri("http://localhost:81/DefaultCollection");
var vssBasicCredential = new VssCredentials(new WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("test", "test")));
using var vssConnection = new VssConnection(uriToServer, vssBasicCredential);
using var graphHttpClient = vssConnection.GetClient<GraphHttpClient>();
var listUsersAsync = await graphHttpClient.ListUsersAsync();
```

And we're getting:

```
handled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (API resource location 005e26ec-6b77-4e4f-a986-b3827bf241f5 is not registered on http://localhost:81/DefaultCollection.) ---> 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssResourceNotFoundException: API resource location 005e26ec-6b77-4e4f-a986-b3827bf241f5 is not registered on http://localhost:81/DefaultCollection.
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.CreateRequestMessageAsync(HttpMethod method, IEnumerable`1 additionalHeaders, Guid locationId, Object routeValues, ApiResourceVersion version, HttpContent content,
IEnumerable`1 queryParameters, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken, String mediaType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Graph.Client.GraphHttpClient.ListUsersAsync(IEnumerable`1 subjectTypes, String continuationToken, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\user\RiderProjects\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 17
```

The same problem as with 2019. Of course other clients are working perfectly.

The same code works perfectly for Azure DevOps Cloud - just have to change VssCredentials to VssBasicCredentials. Thou Basic I know can work for server if SSL is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, currently graph api is not available for Azure DevOps Server 2019 and Server 2020.

[image]

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=22) site, which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

As an alternative, you can try to use [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/devops/user?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-devops-user-show). With the Azure DevOps extension for Azure Command Line Interface (CLI), you can manage many Azure DevOps Services from the command line.

> The Azure DevOps Command Line Interface (CLI) is **available** for Azure
> DevOps Server **2020** and Azure DevOps Services.

About getting started with Azure DevOps CLI ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thanks for response! It would require major changes in architecture in our software to mix REST, SOAP and CLI. But as far as it still works for SOAP (getting users by old API for 2020) it's not a big deal. I was just curious if I've missed something obvious.
Is it possible to turn off SOAP for example for 2021 without implementing GraphClient - different way to get users than azure cli?

Comment: `Is it possible to turn off SOAP for example for 2021 without implementing GraphClient ` I think this  depends on the specific release in the future.